# Проверка формы "на лету"

Tags: html, javascript, php

Как проверять формы на "на лету", т.е. без перезагрузки страницы? Предположим, есть код:

```
<form action="save_user.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <p>
        <input class='input_text' maxlength="255" name="email" placeholder='Адрес электронной почты' required size="15" type="text">
    </p>
    <p>
        <input maxlength="255" name="password" placeholder='Пароль'class='input_text' required size="15" type="password">
    </p>
    <p>
        <input maxlength="255" name="repeat_password" placeholder='Повтор пароля'class='input_text' required size="15" type="password">
    </p>
    <p>
        <input maxlength="255" name="nick" placeholder='Ник в игре'class='input_text' required size="15" type="text">
    </p>
    <p>
        <input maxlength="255" name="name" placeholder='Ваше имя'class='input_text' required size="15" type="text">
    </p>
    <p>
        <input class='input_text' maxlength="255" name="last_name" placeholder='Ваша фамилия' required size="15" type="text">
    </p>
    <br>
    <p>
        <input class='reg' name="submit" type="submit" value="Зарегистрироваться">
    </p>
</form>
```

Необходимо, чтоб содержимое формы обрабатывалось без перезагрузки страницы ...

Comment: Можете более конкретизировать свой вопрос? 

Comment: в onsubmit шлём аякс реквест на проверку данных, ну или сразу данные шлем, сервер возвращает либо успешно либо ошибку

Comment: Я обсолютно не знаком с ява

Comment: @Kirpich643, во-первых, в тегах вашего вопроса, вы указали **javascript**, а не "ява", которую вам никто не предлагал, во-вторых, если и с javascript вы не знакомы, то вопрос преобразуется в формат: "Сделайте за меня". Если это так и есть, то в общем-то ничего страшного, но искать того, кто это сделает, лучше где-нибудь на [фрилансе](https://www.free-lance.ru/). P.S. Кстати, есть [более бюджетный вариант](http://tinyurl.com/js-formchecker)

Comment: Не вы не так понели, я могу сам, но это будет по принцепу: подключаеш jquery , AJAX и ещо пару ккихто непонятных мне скриптов ... Возможно сделать это по другому , проще , чтоб я мог разобратся ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[jQuery form validation](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/)

> This jQuery plugin makes simple clientside form validation trivial, while offering lots of option for customization.